# Android studio error:Error:(22, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments on root project

Tags: android

I have an error in this picture:

[image]

The text of the error is:

> Android studio error:Error:(22, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments on root project

Comment: Please post your code where you encountered the error.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong build.gradle file.

In your top-level file, you can't define an android block.

Just move this part inside the module/build.Gradle file.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'
}
dependencies {
compile files('app/libs/junit-4.12-JavaDoc.jar')
}
apply plugin: 'maven'
```

Comment: There is no module directory